# Angular 2 datepicker two way data binding

Tags: javascript, angular, datepicker, angular2-forms

I have the following code:

```
<div class="input-group date">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right input-sm" id="datepickerTo" [ngModel]="dateTo | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" (ngModelChange)="dateTo = $event" name="nameTo">
</div>
```

I have component class and declared dateTo parameter.

```
public dateTo: Date;

constructor() {
    this.dateTo = new Date();
    this.dateTo.setDate(this.dateTo.getDate() + 30);
}
```

When I load page it shows date properly, but when I change date on picker choose different date, value in component class does not change. Any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: where is the date picker component , are you using angular material for date picking

Comment: The input type is "text" and not "date" . Are you using a 3rd party library for picker? Might bettter to write (change) ="dateTo = parseDate($event.target.value)"  in that case

Comment: I'm using adminlte template. i try to this but same problem<input type="text" class="form-control pull-right input-sm" id="datepickerTo" [ngModel]="dateTo | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" (change) ="dateTo = parseDate($event.target.value)"
                                    name="nameTo">